# Street Light Interference Phenomenon

Tags: energy, electricity

Is there a scientific approach that can explain the [street light interference phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_light_interference_phenomenon)? Everytime I walk past a Streetlight it turns off.

Comment: I am skeptical of such claims until I see a documented experiment. It sounds like metaphysics, not physics. This said, in my first experimental setup, that of a spark gap that would control the charging of a spark chamber, we had to keep the boss away from the setup: when he came nearer than a meter to the spark gap it sparked continuously . Our hypothesis was that for some reason he had an anomalous static field none of the rest of us had.

Comment: Maybe it was your boss's EMP (electromagnetic personality)

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a psychology question, not a physics question. The answer is that you, like every other human, suffer from [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias), which causes you to believe a phenomenon or event happens more often than chance, because you remember the times when it does happen but forget the times when it doesn't.

Comment: And note that balky streetlamps usually go off quickly but regain their glow slowly.  Humans notice fast changes but not slow changes.   Thus people claim to make lamps go off, but not turn lamps on when walking by.

Comment: @DarenW That's a poor explanation.  Even if they went off fast, stayed off for a long time, and then turned on quickly, people would think "street lights toggle when I'm around".  If anything, turning on quickly would increase the perceived effect because two events would trigger it instead of just one.

Answer (score 2):

You asked if there is any **"scientific approach"** that can explain the so-called *street light interference phenomena* and the answer to that is yes.

### One such experiment would be:

**Hypothesis:** Street light interference phenomena exists.

**Prediction:** Street lights don't turn off randomly, they show a bias to turning off when a human is walking nearby.

**Experimental test:** Randomly select many (hundreds or thousands) of street lights and setup recording equipment to monitor when they turn on and off and when humans are nearby.  The more events that are recorded the better.

**Analysis:**  [Perform a statistical test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) to determine if street lights turn of or stay on more than expected when a human walks by.

---

If you perform the above experiment you will find that street light interference phenomena doesn't exist.  If it seems like it does the most likely explanation is [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias).

One way to try to combat this confirmation bias would be that every time you walk under a street light tell yourself "it's about to turn off".  After all of the negative predictions your confidence in the phenomena will probably be diminished (although this isn't a scientific test and it can fail for various reasons).

Comment: now I am tempted to try this out :)

Comment: The above experiment may infirm or confirm the phenomenon. It is doubtful it will explain anything. The confirmation bias theory is at least an explanation of what is observed.  The observation tool is flawed. So this question is related to physics in the sense that checking the reliability of observation tools is essential.